# slow sftp upload to cloud instance bcoz traffic is routed via China backbone network

Tags: networking, cloud

jst wnted to ask abt a problem i hv with my cloud provider i.e. getting slow sftp upload. snt them the requested mtr output thn they explained it was due to some maintenance on a tier 1 isp service provider. from the mtr output i checked the IP with a >50% loss and learned it was described as "CHINANET backbone network". i reasoned with them how come when i connect to my Azure VM i dont get routed using that China IP? or to confirm if their service is stuck with routing traffic thru the China IP and that they couldn't fix it? i nvr received a satisfactory reply.

**can someone hlp to explain if service providers are indeed stuck with routing traffic thru another country's network or IP? can u also hlp to explain why they cnt jst make changes to their network infrastructure to duplicate the way Azure routes their network traffic?**

Comment: 50% packet loss isn't acceptable.  Ever.  If I were you, I'd be looking for a better cloud provider.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. my provider is Cloudcone and they told me they will try to fix the issue by rerouting but no guarantee for a permanent fix since they said they can't control the exact servers the traffic gets routed to. im considering a2hosting or vpsdime at the moment.